# iOS Today Widget share source file with main application

Tags: ios, xcode, today-extension

I've added a Today Extention Widget Project in my Xcode workspace and I want to use some source file from the main app, so I've flagged the "target membership" on this files. The problem is that the Xcode  linker fail with **duplicate symbol** error when compiling the main app. So what is the correct way to share source file between main app and widget?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **`Frameworks`** to share code/files between your `Host App` and `App Extension`.

> You can create an embedded framework to share code between your app
>   extension and its containing app. For example, if you develop an image
>   filter for use in your Photo Editing extension as well as in its
>   containing app, put the filter’s code in a framework and embed the
>   framework in both targets.

For more on sharing scenarios between `Host App` and `App Extension` refer to: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/ExtensionScenarios.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014214-CH21-SW1